# Backup sp site from one farm to another with managed metadata fieds

Tags: managed-metadata

Lets suppose I have a site collection with the enterprise wiki template.
This template has a content type with a categories field which is bound to a managed term.

Lets say in our QA environment, the writers write too many pages and they select the right term on QA.

What happens if I backup-spsite from QA and restore-spsite on production. What will happen with those terms?
Do I have to create them manually before? After?

I can create them manually, but I know the guids wont be the same, if so, what should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling I have answered this question for you before, but anyhow:

You will need to have the same term groups, term sets and terms (with the same ID:s) in both farms.

The normal approach is to do a Backup / Restore of the Manage metadata service database:

> You can use Export-SPMetadataWebServicePartitionData to export term
>   store from source
>   application.http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607847.aspx.
>   You can import  the same in target MMS using
>   Import-SPMetadataWebServicePartitionData
>   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607667.aspx. By using
>   this technique the term store is available on the target. The sspId
>   used internally by the Termstore and referred by Managed metadata
>   columns in list is retained.

(Extract from here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/taj/archive/2011/01/11/site-collection-backup-restore-and-managed-metadata.aspx)

Comment: the problem is in production, there are already other groups and terms, and doing a backup restore will overwrite the existing ones, sorry if I asked before, maybe yes :)

Comment: One approach, not tested by me though, is to create term sets and terms with their constructors taking GUID as a parameter. TermGroups works to by doing TermStore.CreateGroup(string, Guid). To do this you will first need to extract the information for the termsets and terms from your dev env to e.g. an XML file, and then create them again in production by using this extracted information